# My .xml files layout is not showing properly in simulation

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-emulator

In this case, my xml file shows a certain layout while at runtime another one is generated. I am incredibly confused as to why the layout shown at runtime is completely different from the one given. here is the code for the xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signUp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign up!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This displays Insert name here on both a label and button. The button is correctly bound and pressing it does do something, however I cannot type in the textfield at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This one looks fine. Double check if you are changing any property with your java code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one instead. I have removed the useless LinearLayout and try to make the EditText clickable.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signUp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign up!" />
</LinearLayout>
```